# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+3}{x}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+3}{x}}\right)$$

**My approach:** I tried substituting $x=\frac1t$, where $t\to0$. But I was not able to proceed through this because I could not eliminate the $\frac00$ form using this.

I also tried using L'Hopital Rule, but the calculations became too lengthy and I was not able to get the answer.

Comment: With your substitution we get $$ t^{-2} ((1+2t)^{1/2}-(1+3t)^{1/3}.$$ Now you can expand the square root and the cubic root to second order and you will get the desired result.

Comment: @TitoEliatron The second one is a cubic root. Not sure your hint will work :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Didn't see the "3". Sorry. It does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} x^2\left(\sqrt {\frac {x+2}{x}} - \sqrt[3] {\frac {x+3}{x}}\right)$

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} x^2\left(\sqrt {1 + \frac {2}{x}} - \sqrt[3] {1 +\frac {3}{x}}\right)$

$t = \frac 1x$

$\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac {\sqrt {1 + 2t} - \sqrt[3] {1 +3t}}{t^2}$

Let $a = \sqrt {1 + 2t}, b = \sqrt[3] {1 +3t}$

$(a-b)(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5) = a^6-b^6$

$\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac {(a-b)(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}{t^2(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}$

$\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac {(1+2t)^3 - (1+2t)^2}{t^2(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}$

$\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac {3t^2 - 8t^3}{t^2(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}$

$\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac {3 - 8t}{(a^5 + a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}$

As $t$ approaches $0, a^mb^n$ approaches $1.$

$\frac {3}{6} = \frac 12$

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a series expansion:  $$(1+z)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} z^k,$$ and with the choices $$(z,\alpha) \in \{ (2t,1/2), (3t,1/3) \}$$ we get
$$\begin{align}
(1+2t)^{1/2} 
&= 1 + \frac{1/2}{1!}(2t) + \frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)}{2!}(2t)^2 + \frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)(1/2-2)}{3!}(2t)^3 + \cdots \\
&= 1 + t - \frac{1}{2}t^2 + O(t^3), \\
(1+3t)^{1/3} 
&= 1 + \frac{1/3}{1!} (3t) + \frac{(1/3)(1/3-1)}{2!} (3t)^2 + \frac{(1/3)(1/3-1)(1/3-2)}{3!} (3t)^3 + \cdots \\
&= 1 + t - t^2 + O(t^3),
\end{align}$$
hence $$\frac{(1+2t)^{1/2} - (1+3t)^{1/3}}{t^2} = \frac{1}{2} + O(t)$$ and the limit as $t \to 0$ is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

We can multiply by something that will let us to get rid of the difference of roots. $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+3}{x}}\right)= \lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt{(x+2)x}-\sqrt[3]{(x+3)x^2}\right)= \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x\left(({x+2})^3x^3-({x+3})^2x^4\right)}{(x^2+2x)^{\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2+2x)^{2}(x^3+3x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(x^2+2x)^{\frac{3}{2}}(x^3+3x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}+(x^2+2x)(x^3+3x^2)+(x^2+2x)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^3+3x^2)^{\frac{4}{3}}+(x^3+3x^2)^{\frac{5}{3}}}= \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(x^6+6x^5+12x^4+8x^3-x^6-6x^5-9x^4)}{x^5+x^5+x^5+x^5+x^5+x^5+O(x^{\frac{5}{2}})}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{3x^5+8x^4}{6x^5+O(x^{\frac{5}{2}})}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame you didn't show something of what you did using l'Hopital's Rule because you may have given up too soon...

Since  $ \ \lim_{x \ \to \ \infty} \ x^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+3}{x}} \ \right) \ $ has the $ \ \infty · 0 \ $ type of indeterminacy, we will want to re-write the expression as a ratio:

$$ \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \ x^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x}} \ - \ \sqrt[3]{\frac{x+3}{x}} \ \right) \ \ = \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \  \frac{ \left[ \ \left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{1/2} \ - \ \left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{1/3} \ \right]}{\frac{1}{x^2}} \ \  $$

$$ = [LH] \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \  \frac{ \left[ \ \frac12·\left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-1/2} · \left(-\frac{2}{x^2} \right) \ - \ \frac13·\left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-2/3} · \left(-\frac{3}{x^2} \right) \ \right]}{-\frac{2}{x^3}} \ \  $$

$$ =  \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \   {-\frac{x^3}{2}} \ ·  \left[ \ \frac12\left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-1/2} · \left(-\frac{2}{x^2} \right) \ - \ \frac13\left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-2/3} · \left(-\frac{3}{x^2} \right) \ \right] \ \  $$

$$ =  \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \   { \frac{x }{2}} \ ·  \left[ \  \left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-1/2}   \ - \ \left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-2/3}  \ \right] \ \  $$

[this limit still has the same kind of indeterminacy, so we apply the Rule once more; we feel encouraged to do so as the exponent of the multiplying factor has decreased by one]

$$ = [LH] \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \  \frac{ \left[ \ -\frac12·\left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-3/2} · \left(-\frac{2}{x^2} \right) \ - \ \left(-\frac23 \right)·\left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-5/3} · \left(-\frac{3}{x^2} \right) \ \right]}{-\frac{2}{x^2}} \ \  $$

$$ =  \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \    -\frac{x^2}{2}  \ ·  \left[ \ -\frac12·\left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-3/2} · \left(-\frac{2}{x^2} \right) \ + \ \left(\frac23 \right)·\left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-5/3} · \left(-\frac{3}{x^2} \right) \ \right] \ \  $$

$$ =  \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \    \left[ \ -\frac12·\left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-3/2}   \ + \ \left(\frac23 \right)·\left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-5/3} · \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \ \right] \ \  $$

$$ =  \ \  \lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} \          \left(\frac{x+3}{x} \right)^{-5/3}   \ -  \  \frac12·\left(\frac{x+2}{x} \right)^{-3/2}  \ \ = \ \  1^{-5/3}   \ -  \  \frac12·1^{-3/2}  \ \ = \ \  \frac12 \ \ . $$

While I usually advise against using l'Hopital's Rule for limit expressions involving radicals  , there are occasions where they appear in a simple enough way that differentiation doesn't make matters worse  or a radical doesn't just "oscillate" between a numerator and a denominator.